# Проблема с модулем js

Tags: javascript, браузер

Пишу игру на JS, консоль выдает ошибку, я так понял, браузер не доверяет модулю, который загружается неизвестно откуда. Модуль лежит в папке на моем компе, как сделать так, чтобы браузер не выдавал такие ошибки, а модуль подключился?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вебпак смотрите

Comment: Как вы подключаете модуль можете показать?

Comment: В хтмл подключаю index.js
<script type="module" src="./index.js"></script>
А в index.js просто строчка с игровым объектом
import Game from './src/game.js';

Answer (score 0):

Скрипты-модули можно загружать только на сайтах, а из файловой системы нельзя.

Используй сервер. Например [`http-server`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) с ключом `-c-1`.